# Decimal to Gray MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, decimal, mips, qtspim

I'm trying do to a program that convert a decimal number into the gray number.

How can I convert 2147483648?  The result is negative in my program...
Does exist an instruction like lw unsigned?

my program is:

```
 .data

bitmask: .word 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536, 131072, 262144, 524288, 1048576, 2097152, 4194304, 8388608 , 16777216, 33554432 , 67108864 , 134217728 , 268435456 , 536870912, 1073741824 , 2147483648

num: .word 2147483647
.space 12

scrivi: 
.text li $t1,31 
 li $t2,0 #i=0 
li $t3,0 #loop Counter = 8
li $t6,0 #and1 
li $t7,0 #and2 
li $t8,0 #xor 
li $t9,0 #or 
la $s1, num 
la $t2, bitmask 
la $s0, scrivi
 lw $t4,($s1) #$t4 = valore decimale 


loop:

lw $t5, ($t2) #$t5 = bitMask[i] 
and $t6,$t4,$t5 
add $t2,$t2,4 
lw $t5, ($t2) #$t5 = bitMask[i] 
and $t7,$t4,$t5 
srl $t7,$t7,1 
xor $t8,$t6,$t7 
or $t9,$t9,$t8 
addi $t3,$t3,1 
bne $t3,$t1 loop

and $t7,$t4,$t5 
xor $t8,$t7,$zero 
or $t9,$t9,$t8

sw $t9, ($s0)

li $v0,10 syscall
```

Comment: how can I do it with unsigned number and not with ca2 numbers?

Comment: What *is* the result you get?  Unsigned `2147483648` is negative if you print it with a function that interprets the value in a register as signed, because it has the high bit set.  Also, you don't need a lookup-table for `1<<n`; construct that on the fly with a shift instruction!

Comment: I get -1073741824

Comment: I change the program like i wrote in the comment

Comment: You posted an answer, not a comment.  [edit] your question if you have changes.  (And delete your non-answer before it gets downvotes).

Comment: Thank I changed it

Comment: You didn't use code-formatting, though, so it's a total mess again, like it was before my first edit. 
 Highlight your code and hit control-k, or click the code-format button above the edit window.

Comment: Sorry I think now it's ok

Comment: `lw $t4,($s1) #$t4 = valore decimale` - just a side note (as looking at source), this will load binary value. `t4` is 32 **bit** register in the CPU, i.e. it's 32 physical cells holding electricity current, and by the level of that current the CPU understands particular cell value as "0" or "1". You have decimal string in source code `2147483647`, which is converted into binary by the assembler during compilation. The CPU does get 32 bit binary value from memory. (the compiled code is stored in memory as another sequence of bits, everything in computer is binary encoded, no other way for CPU).

Comment: `Does exist an instruction like lw unsigned?`  LW doesn't care about signed/unsigned.  It's the `syscall` that you're using to print the result that decides whether to decode it as signed or unsigned.

Comment: I know that sys call 36 print unsigned number but on my qtspim doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't work how?  See [mcve] for hints on describing problems accurately.

Comment: To print an unsigned integer I know that exist sys call 36 but when I use it says "unknown sys call 36"

Comment: Yes, SPIM does not have unsigned int output function (but MARS does, the 36 one). So if you did expect result `2147483648` and you did got `-2147483648`, then your calculation itself is correct, and only output is interpreting your value as signed integer instead of unsigned. What are your options: if you really need full 32 bit unsigned integers decimal output, then you will have to write your own value->string converter, and output the integer as string. If 31 bits are enough, then you are already done (if the code is correct). Or use MARS simulator and syscall 36, if you can switch spim?

Comment: How can I do a value-string converter in this program?

Comment: there's ton of answers just here on SO (although probably not that many for MIPS, but Peter Cordes did gave you some link to other question in the comment on your Fib. question, check it thoroughly for further hints), and ton of tutorials/articles about that, it's basic math/computer/asm stuff, just make sure you understand how/why are numbers written the way we do, and that you can by hand on paper convert decimal to binary or hexadecimal and back, so you fully understand the logic behind it. Then check the computer/asm articles, what kind of algorithms are used for that.